# Altera MAX10 Clock primitives without synchronization?

Tags: fpga, max10

Irrespective of the relative evil of gating clocks in FPGAs my understanding was that one should synchronize the enable signal to the clock being gated by means of a flip-flop chain.

However, while studying the documentation for the MAX10 device I stumbled over the following section: [Clock Enable Signals](https://www.altera.com/documentation/mcn1395213337540.html#mcn1395926825834) where the figures 5 and 6 seem to indicate that no synchronization seems to be necessary.

[image: Figure 5]

[image: Figure 6]

Do I miss something?

Answer (score 1):

This only applies to "signals when switching the clock source to the PLLs or GCL". So if you want to switch a clock to a PLL then you can do so by disabling one clock and enabling another. The PLL functions like a clock buffer to some extent. However downstream from the PLL the clock should not be ran through logic because it will provide a mismatch of timing.